# django celery func.delay dont exetute func

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am working on a django project with 2 apps.
I added a celery task in app A and this task calls another method in `tasks.py` in app B.
The method in app B is called as follows

```
send_mail_task_B.delay(subject=subject,
                         from_email=from_email,
                         to_email=to_email,
                         bcc_email=bcc_email,
                         body=body,
                         html_message=html_message)
```

`send_email_task_B` doesnt get executed with the `.delay`,
but when I remove `.delay` it executes and sends emails.
My `__init__.py` file in django project conf is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
celery_app
```

I am using Django 2.2.8 and celery 4.3.0.

I am running celery task in django shell as follows:

```
from A.tasks import send_email_method
result=send_email_method_A.apply()
```

Comment: did you run the second app as a celery worker or as a django app. To execute the task the second app must be run as a celery worker.

Comment: @Sebastian Stigler yes it worked when I run the celery worker, thank you